# Akka stream timeout in long pipeline

Tags: akka-stream

If I have a very long akka-stream pipeline, is there a way to handle timeouts such that the timeout doesn't start until the first element gets to a given spot in a pipeline?

For example, let's say I have a pipeline in which it takes the first element 2+ minutes to reach the final sink, but after that, elements should come in every second or so. Is this something akka has taken into account? Or do I have to set timeouts on my graph shapes individually in this case?

Comment: Are you using the "timeout" for completion of the entire stream or processing time for each element?

Comment: What do you mean by "using" it? I'm talking about `stream.materializer.subscription-timeout` if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Do you want the timeout to trigger if all of the elements havent completed in a certain period of time?  Or, do you want the timeout to trigger if one element took too long to get through the flow?